# Heroku errors H12 and H28 Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, request, axios

My Node.js/Express server is deployed with Heroku

Sometimes, I have H12 or H28 errors.
From what  I know, these errors occurs when user has a low connection.

I am new on Heroku and I didn't figure out what is the best solution in this case.
I am wondering if an upgrade of Dynos type (currently hobby type) would be sufficient.

Or Do I have to add Worker Dynos, Background Jobs and Queueing. In this case  "hobby Dynos"  type would be enough ?

Thanks a lot for your help !
[image]

Comment: Heya Lila! There is a lot of things that can cause that issue. Perhaps showing us your entire code on github so we can have a closer look

Comment: Hello Henry! Thank you for your answer :))
The repo is private, I can’t share it, but  I can explain the steps.

App
User take a picture (react native app)
then the picture is resized 
then the user is localized
then the picture is sent to the server (axios post formdata)

Back
I add res.setTimout(500000) in my route
then (sometimes) H28 or H12 errors occurre

Comment: Oh so your app is deployed but when you hit that route it crashes the app? So the error can't be your project structure or package.json. Does that route utilize an environment variable? You might need to take a picture of the heroku error

Comment: Yes it crashes the app but it seems to happen when the user has low connection. I add a picture of the error on my initial message